# typescript tuple in class heritance, lost types

Tags: javascript, typescript, tuples, variadic-tuple-types

how i can override a class array with tuple and add native instance in index and keep the types ?

how i can make this valid, what can be the correct syntax ?

playground: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8CwAoAkABwE4HsAXBYYgE2mAAsBLEM3BAOwH4AueCBAbQF0MAvhlCQYAYXxNCYGkwS4YCAB7EmZGJyRp00aAHo90EAkLQIYAJ4AaSpOmz50ZoRqELlME2hUwANyTUdAzMMAAUElIycgoAPgAKuDQAtq40-hAAlBg4BMSkCBT4-riJZAG09IxMbACCJZYAPBH20RDxiSku6QB8ANzQghjC4FDQCcmp6U4qzOpwiCiD6MOi0DXTqnPNUfIw2vqGADImZpZr3n5IEPhJSExgXUiyENJMwE9egZXM0Nw1Vv9YFYAHSg7YOWLjTppBAQfhYPBEEjkaBFeSlcpBKpsP4AqywXjQAC8vzkAHc1qEMlZyZTqbTYFTeL0MAdoIi8ii0SUaGVKBVgl4SdxaTUqTSEBSxfTJXAmf0DNAyTQqPgAK6mNzYJBgEDXaBMIhK-C4ADW0BYAEJsrJXFTtJhMMBJC9oDQAAzE6CEWgQYFfQXcd3M7JOl2mGgARi9PpofoDVW4keZAywYaYrpoACYY77-QLE1mU6HnRmIwBmXNx-NY5jccspxUQVVq%20jQcGtdoTR5tNVqBAAMwcFBY2SEy3Q45Eo1gG1m4jsOwUiwnAiAA)

```js
class Base {
    protected children?:Base[]
}
class Containers extends Base {
    protected override children:Array<Containers|Primitives>; 
}

class Primitives extends Base {
}

class A extends Containers {
 // so children should automaticly someting like : [A,A,B,...Containers|Primitives] ?
    protected override children:[A,A,B]
    init(){
        const i0 = this.children[0];
        const i1 = this.children[1]; 
        const i2 = this.children[2]; 
        const i3 = this.children[3]; // should Containers|Primitives|undefined because extends Containers ?
    }

}
class B extends Containers {

}
```

So in this code A can have native instance in `children` index, where i use getter .
But ...rest of `children` should auto herite parent `Containers|Primitives` no ?

Also this is weird , if i remove type, everything became instance A ?!!
[image]

EDIT: I see i can write like this !
`protected override children:[A,...Array<Containers|Primitives>]` 
But i repeat code from parent class, is there a good way to avoid repeat ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
class Base {
    protected children?: Base[]
}
class Containers extends Base {
    // let say, container entity can have childrens (Containers|Primitives)
    protected override children: Array<Containers | Primitives> = [];
}

class Primitives extends Base {
}

class A extends Containers {
    // Let say A have some native instance in children [A,A,B,...Containers|Primitives]
    protected override children: [A, A, B, ...Containers[] | Primitives[]] = [new A(), new A(), new B()];
    init() {
        const i0 = this.children[0];
        const i1 = this.children[1];
        const i2 = this.children[2];
        const i3 = this.children[3]; // // Primitives | Containers
    }

}
class B extends Containers {

}
```

You need to use spread syntax

`[A,A,B,...Containers|Primitives]` does not compile because you are allowed to use `...` only with arrays

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8CwAoAkABwE4HsAXBYYgE2mAAsBLEM3BAOwH4AuORAbQF0MBfDKEgwAwviaEwNJglwwEAD2JMyMeBCRoseIiXLR8ANzm4aZJNToNmHAIK5cYAJ4AecZOmz50AD7QABTMAWxpCGhMIAD5oAF5oXgBuAQwhcChAkLCIhAVlZjVOTRQU9DSRaDtoJRVCjykZORhtHAJiUgQKY1NzS1p6RiYOLjsAGkrx2HGAOln6rybeP0yaUPDI3h44hNkAd0qACgBKcb3Dk%20gz2GOeZKwZMOOSrExgCQhCaBoABm3CWgg0ysA2YXG%20twwmFe70%20NAAjH8AUD%20jYmFw4RCXm8mB8vgAmRE0QHA1FcPGYqHY3E0ADMhOJKMGXBpt2gAHo2Ss1jkYP55o15JDBGV0MLhBlYNV8qoxBIGt5mqlRUA)

`children` is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer, so explicit type annotation is required

Comment: I'm looking for a slightly more automatic way without repeating the code written in the parent class, can you confirm that these are the only way?

Comment: i add a edit on the post: i can do `protected override children:[A,...Array<Containers|Primitives>]` but `Array<Containers|Primitives>` is alrealy know by parent class, so we should have a way to avoid repeat this ? no ?

Comment: children is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer, so explicit type annotation is required

Comment: okey , thanks for fast hawser you are awesome, i close :)